# How do I convert data from tkinter label widget into float for predictive function

Tags: python, machine-learning, tkinter, data-mining

I'm trying to predict a set of values given by the user

```
ty = [fst.get(), snd.get(), trdget(), fth.get(), ffth.get(), sxth.get(), svth.get(), eth.get()]
yow=rfcmodel.predict(ty)
print(yow)
```

ty is a list of variables, wherein the variables are:

```
fst = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
snd = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
trd = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
fth = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
ffth = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
sxth = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
svth = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
eth = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
```

and it gives me an error value of: could not convert string to float:

Am I missing something?

Full Traceback Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Zayn Justin/PycharmProjects/Software Engineering/Expert System with GUI.py", line 140, in <module>
    ty = [[float(fst.get()),  float(snd.get()), float(trd.get()), float(fth.get()), float(ffth.get()), float(sxth.get()), float(svth.get()), float(eth.get())]]
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

EDIT: I've also tried doing

```
fst = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
fstb = float(fst.get())
snd = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
sndb = float(snd.get())
trd = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
trdb = float(trd.get())
fth = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
fthb = float(fth.get())
ffth = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
ffthb = float(ffth.get())
sxth = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
sxthb = float(sxth.get())
svth = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
svthb = float(svth.get())
eth = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
ethb = float(ethb.get())

ty = [[fstb, sndb, trdb, fthb, ffthb, sxthb, svthb, ethb]]
```

Still it gives me,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Zayn Justin/PycharmProjects/Software Engineering/Expert System with GUI.py", line 39, in <module>
    fstb = float(fst.get())
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: Provide us  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I want my model to predict something by using the input data given by the user, which comes from this fst = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
snd = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
trd = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
fth = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
ffth = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
sxth = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
svth = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
eth = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
however, it won't accept the data entered and gives me the error above.

Comment: You should post the full error traceback.

Comment: Most likely there are empty strings in those entries.  Try to print out the values of those entries before passing them to the predict function.

Comment: *When* are you doing all of those `.get()` calls?  All too often I've seen people do that on the very next line of code after the creation of the Entries - so that the code executes before the user has even had a chance to see the Entries, and has certainly had no time to actually type anything into them.

Comment: You get empty strings from those entries because they are just created and no content is input in those entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing in null values.

I suggest trying this one out

```
for x in root.winfo_children():
    if x.winfo_class() == 'Entry':
        if x.get() != '':
            # push all to the array
            print(float(x.get()))
            ty.append(float(x.get()))
```

-Eli

EDIT: You can also try printing out the values first. added the print statement

Comment: Thank you! I finally got it!

Answer (score -1):

Have you used a variable to store the data of the users inputs.

Eg,

```
fst_val = fst.get()
```

And them use it in to the list.

Hope it works...

Comment: hello, thank you for your input, but unfortunately, it hasn't solved my problem. I really appreciate the comment.